# Setting MessageBox type conditionally

Tags: sapui5

How do I set the type of MessageBox based on a variable?

For example I have a warning MessageBox:

```js
MessageBox.warning("My Message", {
    ...
});
```

But, say for example I only want to display a warning MessageBox if a variable 'warning' is true, otherwise create a confim MessageBox.

```js
if (warning){
    MessageBox.warning("My Message", {
        ...
    });
} else {
    MessageBox.confirm("My Message", {
        ...
    });
}
```

However the above code is totally unmanageable as the body of the message contains a lot of code.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

1. As the MessageBox methods only do a MessageBox.show with some settings preset, you could just use `show` and redo those settings.
2. You can use a different notation of JavaScript to call different functions:

   ```js
   var method = warning ? "warning" : "confirm";
   MessageBox[method]("My Message", {
       ...
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Messagebox.show worked great for me, just changed the properties within that